# How to compare the type in a constexpr?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Is there a way that I could make a better comparison for the `first` and `last` if? For instance, if I wanted a different behavior for `float` and `double`. Is there a way to compare using the actual type (not its size in memory) inside constexpr? Here is the code I have:

```
void print(T val)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof(T) == 1) {
        printf("%c", val);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
        printf("%d", val);
    }
    else if constexpr (sizeof(T) == sizeof(float)) {
        printf("%f", val);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    print(5.5f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Similar to `std::is_integral_v`, there is [`std::is_floating_point_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point).

Comment: And if you actually decide to write C++ instead of C you will find that you don't need to do any of this at all, and simply do `std::cout << val;`. What problem are you trying to solve, with all of this?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you really need to be so aggressive with everybody who asks a question?

Comment: The `Is_integral` test is insufficient to guarantee that the data is suitable for use with the `%d` format code

Comment: Also note that just because `constexpr if` can be forced to do something doesn't mean it is appropriate for the task.  Type-based dispatch should be done using overloading or specialization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I pasted an example from a book

Comment: @RSahu this would return true to both float and double, right? I want to be able to tell the difference

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the problem I'm trying to solve is just understand the concept and how to apply it.

Comment: That's a pretty bad example, from that book. It would help, in the future, to mention that in order to provide the relevant context. In any case, any C++ book that teaches you to use `printf` in C++ code needs to be thrown away and replaced by a better C++ book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes!**

You're looking for [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
void print(T val)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>) {
        printf("%c", val);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
        printf("%d", val);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) {
        printf("%f", val);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    print(5.5f);
    return 0;
}
```

N.B. that first condition isn't *quite* the same as yours (e.g. `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `std::byte`…), but you can modify to suit.

Also, `%d` is for `int` (after promotions are applied to `val`); your `is_integral_v<T>` check is not sufficient to guarantee that.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was looking for. thank you! =)